# Retrieve Instagram media by hashtag

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-api

I'm trying to fetch Instagram posts tagged with some concrete #hashtag to build a custom feed in my app.

This was possible using legacy API: https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/tags/. However, according to developer documentation, Instagram deprecates its own API in favour of new Graph API. I don't see any direct replacement for this. The closest thing is the "Mentions API" (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/mentions) from which you can obtain media where your company has been mentioned (via @company in a comment/caption or by mentioning company name on a photo itself).

So, is there any viable alternative to the legacy API to obtain user media tagged with #hastag or it's officially forbidden now?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know there is no reliable way to reproduce getting pictures by tag. Please keep in mind that new Graph API is dedicated only to Instagram Business Accounts. It will not work with regular Instagram accounts.

Another thing is that `/tag` endpoints in old Instagram API requires `public_content` permission. Unfortunately submitting new apps with this feature is forbidden - https://www.instagram.com/developer/changelog/. Right now for old Instagram API you can use basic permission only.

The only way IMHO is to scrape content of tag page by script running on your server. However this is not ideal solution and should be avoided. Too many requests can result in blocking your server IP.

**Update 24.04.2019**

Instagram Graph API now includes the Hashtag Search API so you can get pictures by tag. Docs for this functionality can be found here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/hashtag-search

Comment: are there rules about scraping? i do know that facebook forbids it, but i am not sure if that´s only for facebook.com or instagram too. after all, facebook owns instagram.

Comment: @luschn Yes, there is something like that in Instagram terms - https://help.instagram.com/478745558852511 (General conditions, point 10.)

Comment: So they prohibit me to access my own data? This starts to be ridiculous.

Comment: @FilippoDeLuca well, it depends how you want to access your own data. If you are regular user you can access it by visiting your profile page, your app etc. If you want to access it like from your script etc. you need to use their official APIs. Either old Instagram API or new Instagram Graph API.

Comment: @Astaz3l they have removed access to the old API. And for the new GraphQL API, only instagram_basic access can be requested. The other permissions are not allowed anymore to anyone, only facebook partners can obtain them.

Comment: @FilippoDeLuca well, the old API still works, but only with basic permission. So you can't really use that for fetching pictures by tag. However Graph API has now Hashtag Search API that you might use: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/hashtag-search
It requires Instagram Public Content Access and you don't need to by Facebook Partner to use this feature. You need to have a verified Business (it will not work for Individuals) and sign the contract with Facebook. And your use case must be accepted during App Review.